# Why doesn't react-router-redux work when using a custom basename?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am trying to create a React app that can be hosted at an arbitrary path other than the root - `"/"`

So, I am trying to apply a custom `basename` using `react-router-redux`. I am creating a custom `browserHistory` using the `createBrowserHistory` module from the `history` package, but this seems to result in nothing being rendered. When I use the `browserHistory` module that comes with `react-router`, it works.

Sample code that works:

```
import App from 'App'
import NoMatch from 'NoMatch'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    // reducers
  })
)

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/foo" component={App}></Route>
        <Route path="*" status={404} component={NoMatch}/>
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Of course, this doesn't allow me to set the `basename` dynamically. It is always `/foo/`.

Here is what I am trying in order to set it dynamically:

```
import App from 'App'
import NoMatch from 'NoMatch'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    // reducers
  })
)

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({
  basename: window.location.pathname
});

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}></Route>
        <Route path="*" status={404} component={NoMatch}/>
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

But, when I do this, the app does nothing. The `App` component is not rendered - nor is the `NoMatch` component - so it would appear that the problem is not the routes, but something is keeping `Router` from even starting up.

Any ideas?

Versions of the relevant modules:

```
"react": "^0.14.7"
"redux": "^3.3.1"
"react-redux": "^4.4.6"
"react-router": "^2.0.0"
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.7"
"history": "^4.4.1"
```

Comment: v4 of `history` is for v4 of `react-router`. You should be using v3 of `history`, although I can't say for certain that that will fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem - thanks! Though, I need to be using v2 of `history`. Also, in v2 of `history`, there is no `createBrowserHistory`, it is just `createHistory`. If you want to make an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: No problem. v3 of RR should be an API compatible version of v2, it just removes the deprecated code from RR v1. I'm not sure what history differences exist that cause v3 of `history` to be incompatible with v2.0.0 of `react-router`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v4 of `history` is for v4 of `react-router` and there are breaking API changes that make it incompatible with previous versions of `react-router`. v2/3 of `history` should be used with v2/3 of `react-router`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Root from 'src/Root/Root';
import configureStore from 'src/store/configureStore'
// import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history'
let browserHistory = useBasename(createHistory)({
  basename: '/base'
})

const store = configureStore()
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

ReactDOM.render( <Root store={store} history={history} />, document.getElementById('appRoot'));
```

this code works fine with

```
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.5.2",
    "console-polyfill": "^0.2.3",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.9",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "history": "3.2.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-constants": "^0.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.7.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-immutablejs": "^0.0.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "0.11.1"
  }
```

[image]